# gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof

Tags: windows, python-3.x, gnupg

I am using Python v3.6.5 (Anaconda), python-gnupg v2.3.1, gpg.exe v1.4.22 and while decrypting I am getting below error:

> ERROR:root:gpg: can't create D:/folder/flder/pgb\D:/folder/flder/pgbsecring.gpg.lock':
>       gpg: keyblock resourceD:/folder/flder/pgb\D:/folder/flder/pgbsecring.gpg': general error
>       gpg: can't create D:/folder/flder/pgb\D:/folder/flder/pgbpubring.gpg.lock':
>       gpg: keyblock resourceD:/folder/flder/pgb\D:/folder/flder/pgbpubring.gpg': general error
>       gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
>       [GNUPG:] NODATA 1
>       [GNUPG:] NODATA 2
>       gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof

Below is my code:

```
import gnupg
gpg=gnupg.GPG(homedir='D:/folder/flder/pgb',binary='C:/Users/Anaconda3/Lib/GNU/gpg.exe')
status = pgp.decrypt(gpg, res_files['fname'], gpcnf['passphrase'], outfile)

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase=passphrase, output=outfile)
```

Comment: Not a windows expert, but have you tried using `\\` instead of `/` as directory separator?

Comment: Yes using \ gives another error invalid argument

Comment: Sorry, formatting problem. What I meant is "\\" instead of "/". Share the full error details if you get an error

Comment: I changed homedir = /gnupg now I am able to read my secret keys and fingerprint from key file.     But error: ERROR:root:gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
[GNUPG:] NODATA 1
[GNUPG:] NODATA 2
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof          is still there.